# Comment subject field too large breaks the page layout

Tags: 7, comments, emails

I activated a contributed theme and I am doing some little customization. At the moment I have a 2 columns layout (content + second sidebar). Originally the theme was designed with a much larger content column hence after reducing its size I realized the comment subject field was too large for the content column.

Looking in the theme style.css file was of no help. I am trying to reduce the `size` of the comment subject field from 60 to 40 in the following portion of HTML code:

```
<input id="edit-subject" class="form-text" type="text" maxlength="64" size="60" value="" name="subject">
```

but I do not understand where/what part of drupal php code generates it. I am also afraid I will meet the same problem once the contact form is enabled.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right I got it. I fixed it in the `style.css` file

WAS:

```
.form-text {
    border: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #949494;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}
```

IS

```
.form-text {
    border: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #949494;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    width: 75%;              /* <-- added line */
}
```